# How to connect to SQL Server from Python Flask?

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, pyodbc

I have been trying to connect to SQL Server from Flask but with no luck.

I can connect to DB when i try in my Local Machine and it works perfectly fine, but when i try to connect from VM/Remote Desktop, i see the below error.

I have spent lot of time trying to figure out the issue and for solution, but no luck.
I suspect something should be with firewalls or security.

Thanks in Advance for help.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
        'Server=DEV001;'
        'Database=ZXCZ;'
        'user=gendb;'
        'Password=qwe123;')
```

```
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]
[DBNETLIB]SSL Security error (18) (SQLDriverConnect); 
[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]
[DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()). (1); 
[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')
```

Comment: Are you sure `{SQL Server}` is the right driver? https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows

Comment: ``{SQL Server}`` worked fine when i try in my Local Machine, but i see issues only when i try in Virtual Machine.

Comment: Be sure to use appropriate [ODBC parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/dsn-connection-string-attribute?view=sql-server-ver15). Use `uid` and `pwd` instead of *user* and *password*. Also, remember a virtual machine is *different* environment than local machine. It must have network or remote access to database and installed ODBC drivers.

Comment: The VM could have different drivers to your local machine...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use the latest version of ODBC, that you can find here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server

At the bottom of the page you'll also find a link to Installation document, in case you're installing in on something different than Windows.

Also, the connection string should look like

```
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=;
```